# Write a Python program to remove duplicates from a list of integers, preserving order

Tags: python, list

So this was the question and I implemented it using python language but there is error in code and I am not able to fix it so please help. I am attaching code also.

```
def delete23(a):
    for i in range(0, len(a) - 1):
        for j in range(0, len(a) - 1):
            if a[i] == a[j] and i != j:
                a.pop(j)
    print(a)


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 7]
print(len(a))
delete23(a)
```

[image]

Comment: Once you pop an element, the list is shorter than it originally was. This will cause your `j` to reach an index that's out of range.

Comment: when yo remove values then `a` will not have the same `len`. also your algorithm have some flaws

Comment: Can you please rectify the error then I mean I want to do this problem using list so how can I then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter duplicates while preserving the order, a set of seen values is used quite often. The logic is very simple: if a value is not present yet in seen, the value is encountered for the first time.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 7]

seen = set()
lst2 = []
for x in lst:
    if x not in seen:
        seen.add(x)
        lst2.append(x)
    
print(lst2)
```

With a little trick, this can be shortened:

```
seen = set()
lst2 = [(seen.add(x) or x) for x in lst if x not in seen]

print(lst2)
```

To explain the expression inside (...): `set.add` returns `None` and `(None or VALUE)` is evaluated to `VALUE`

---

Warning: ALL solutions using a set or a dict require that all values are hashable.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot 'pop' out values while you are iterating forward through the list because the next index will be skipped (as subsequent items are shifted by one position) and your list's length will decrease which causes your loops to go out of bounds.

If you processed the list in reversed order of indexes, this would not be a problem because the shifted positions would only be at indexes that you have already processed (as long as you pop out the index from the outer loop `i` instead of `j`).

For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 7]

for i in reversed(range(len(a))): # going backward through positions
    if a.index(a[i]) < i:         # if another exists before i
        a.pop(i)                  # remove the duplicate at i

print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary to filter out duplicates (which only preserves unique keys and maintains original order):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 7]

*a, = dict.fromkeys(a)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

If the order didn't need to be preserved, you could have used a set.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 7, 5]  # added a 5 to illustrate loss of order

*a, = {*a}

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Comment: wow this is simple, beautifull

Comment: I'm partial to `list(set(a))` myself, but I think that can affect ordering if I'm not mistaken

Comment: indeed, sets don't preserve the order of their input

Comment: ya @JRiggles I was thinking the same but then set data type in unordered ,although in pycharm it is printing the elements in order...

Comment: @Pari, that's probably a coincidence.  If you change the order of the original list, you should see a difference (e.g. `[7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1]`)

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking about `dict.fromkeys()` but, @Alain already answered brilliantly.

There is one method in `more_itertools` which preserves the order.

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 7]
list(unique_everseen(a))
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```